# how to overide prvatemsg url 'messages' to 'something'?

Tags: uri, redirection, privatemsg

function _MY_MODULE_custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['redirect'] = url('thank-you', array('absolute' => true));
}

Comment: Can you be more descriptive, providing module details, screenshots etc ?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to do a redirect to a thank you page after you handle your form posted data then just add to your function a redirect via a call [drupal_goto()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7).

Something like this:

```
function _MY_MODULE_custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // process your form stuff...
  drupal_goto('thank-you');  // redirect to page 'thank-you' providing this is one of your drupal pages
}
```

Comment: when u login u will get a message tag like "You have 16 unread messages" while clicking on it will redirect to /message . form der i want to change url./something @rtome